# CloudFront Modify JS / CSS Content

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

My website's theme is broken when I am serving JS and CSS via CloudFront. Further troubleshooting shows that some JS and CSS contents are different from the origin and I suspect this is the reason. Is it possible that CF has some kind of optimization features that modify our JS /CSS content? If yes, how can we disable or fix this problem?

I believe it is not a caching problem due to there isn't any changes to the origin's file after CF enabled. Also, I've tried to invalidated /wp-content/uploads/sites/2386/bb-plugin/cache/* but still getting the same behavior. As shown in the print screen below, I've also set query string to "Forward all, cache based on all".

Below are the JS and CSS files that are different by comparing the origin and CF, and my CF settings print screen:

**JS**

- **(Origin)** https://www.seeustosee.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2386/bb-plugin/cache/2650-layout.js?ver=774d199e19697e00bc26b83ff78afa2c
- **(CF)** https://da4e1j5r7gw87.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/2386/bb-plugin/cache/2650-layout.js?ver=774d199e19697e00bc26b83ff78afa2c

**CSS**

- **(Origin)** https://www.seeustosee.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2386/bb-plugin/cache/2650-layout.css?ver=774d199e19697e00bc26b83ff78afa2c
- **(CF)** https://da4e1j5r7gw87.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/2386/bb-plugin/cache/2650-layout.css?ver=774d199e19697e00bc26b83ff78afa2c

**CF Behavior Settings**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkUKw.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront does not modify payload.  Even when `Compress Objects Automatically` is enabled (which it isn't), the compression is transparent gzip that results in a response body identical to the original, after decompression.

But take a look at your response headers, and you'll see the problem.  Your origin server is Nginx, but you don't have CloudFront configured to use that server as the origin for these requests.  You have CloudFront sending the requests to an Amazon S3 bucket.  The JS file there is from August 28, 2019.

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 18371
Date: Fri, 31 Jan 2020 02:21:42 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Aug 2019 06:53:02 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice I've set a special origin group a long time ago.